# The IControllerFactory 'Spring.Web.Mvc.SpringControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Account

Tags: asp.net, spring-mvc

I am getting problem like

"The IControllerFactory 'Spring.Web.Mvc.SpringControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Account'" . What does this mean?????

I am calling Logon method from controller named Account.
but when same file is kept in home controller and called then it renderes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case I was using Spring.NET Dependency Injection and I forgot to declare the `AccountController` object dependency in the XML file.

One year later, I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in a Spring.NET Spring.Web.Mvc.SpringControllerFactory:

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    IController controllerInstance = null;
    if (controllerType != null)
    {
        IDictionary objectsOfType = ApplicationContext.GetObjectsOfType(controllerType);
        if (objectsOfType.Count > 0)
        {
            controllerInstance = (IController)objectsOfType.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().First<DictionaryEntry>().Value;
        }
    }
    else // there should be if (contollerInstance == null)
    {
        controllerInstance = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
    this.AddActionInvokerTo(controllerInstance);
    return controllerInstance;
}
```

If controllerInstance cannot be gained from a Spring container - it should be retrieved from a base class (DefaultControllerFactory).

Comment: This issue was reported and fixed for 2.0 M1. See [SPRNET-1482](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-1482)